# AngularJS $http and WebApi 2

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an issues which has just arisen.
I have a Web API that has this method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(OrderRequestViewModel model)
{
    var order = new orderHeader()
    {
        sordNo = model.OrderNumber,
        process = orderHeader.orderProcesses.Read
    };

    order.processInfos.read_CoreHistory = model.ReadCoreHistory;

    var response = this.Connection.webServicesAdvanced.ordersHubAction_S(this.SecurityToken, order);

    switch (response.state)
    {
        case processorResult.resultEnum.failed:
        case processorResult.resultEnum.validationfailed:
            throw new HttpException(500, response.info);
        default:
            return Ok(new OrderResponseViewModel(response.obj));
    }
}
```

The **OrderRequestViewModel** only has 2 properties: OrderNumber (string) and ReadCoreHistory (boolean).

In my **Angular JS** application I have a service which looks like this:

```
.factory('OrderService', ['$http', '$filter', 'apiUrl', function ($http, $filter, api) {
    var _get = function (orderNumber, readCoreHistory) {
        return $http.get(api + 'orders?orderNumber=' + orderNumber + '&readCoreHistory=' + readCoreHistory);
    }

    //-- removed for brevity --//

    var service = {};

    service.get = _get;

    //-- removed for brevity --//

    return service;
}])
```

When I call the **get()** method from my controller, if I have fiddler open it states:

> > No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'OrderRequestViewModel' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.

Apparently this is a content type header issue, but I have no access to the ajax call options that I can see. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: On the comment of @kmcnamee; I would make sure your call is actually hitting the expected end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET` method does not have a body, complex types are filled by data from request body in ASP.NET WebAPI, you should add `[FromUri]` attribute before your complex type in method signature.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] OrderRequestViewModel model)
{ ...
```